# Query returns boolean instead of mysqli_query

Tags: php

Need help with

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

I'm trying to do a steamOpenID login button, but I get an error when it comes to my mysqli_query, it returns a boolean. Is it a problem with my database or in the code?

```
$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?
key=$_STEAMAPI&steamids=$matches[1]";
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
{
  $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM `SteamOpenID` WHERE `steamid`=$player->steamid";
  $query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);

  // This line triggers the warning
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query_id) == 0){
    $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO SteamOpenID (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES ('$player->personaname','$player->steamid','$player->avatar')";
    mysqli_query($db,$sql_steam);
```

Comment: You should use prepared statements and bind variables, but when you use `$player->steamid` as a string substitution, you need to put `{$player->steamid}` (add braces round it)

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for taking your time helping.

Comment: Where are you defining `$db`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, mysql_query is a very old function and has been deprecated as it clearly says in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Secondly, you don't bother to check if [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) actually worked. This returns FALSE on failure. You should check the result using the strict equality comparison operator **===** (3 equal signs) like so:

```
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
if ($json_object === FALSE) {
    die("could not fetch the remote url");
}
```

Thirdly, you don't bother to check of the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) worked either. The docs say it will return **NULL** if the JSON cannot be decoded.

```
if (is_null($json_decoded)) {
    die("JSON decoded as NULL");
}
```

You should also probably do some sanity checking on $json_decoded. But, assuming you get the array you want and assuming each player has a steamid property, it might just work.

I'd probably change your SQL definition to this:

```
$sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM `SteamOpenID` WHERE `steamid`=" . mysql_real_escape_string($player->steamid);
```

You should **always** validate and/or escape input before you put it in your queries or you risk [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

And finally, we come to the problem at hand, which is that you don't bother to check the result of [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) before you just start using other functions on it. As the documentation says:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error. You should check what it returns before to make sure it didn't return false before you start running other functions on it.

```
$query_id = mysql_query($sql_fetch_id);
if (!$query_id) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

You'll probably find that your SQL has an error.

EDIT: I also just noticed that you are supplying two parameters to mysql_query. The first param you supply to that function should be your SQL query string. The code you provided also doesn't tell us where you defined $db. You should probably reverse those two parameters. Read [the docs](http://php.net/mysql_query) and you'll see that the first parameter is the query string and the second parameter is the link identifier that you got when you called mysql_connect. It's an optional parameter. If you don't supply it, the function will *use the last connection opened using mysql_connect.*

Comment: Now im getting 'Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in  on line 40 Invalid query:' btw im new to working with sql, sry that my comments might sound stupid.

Comment: If you use [mysqli_query](http://php.net/mysqli_query) instead of [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query), then it works a little differently -- you have to keep track of the connection originally made. If you are updating to the newer mysqli functions (a good idea), it'll require more work. Read the docs on those functions and make sure you are supplying the necessary parameters.

Comment: @lunatiC I just noticed your code calls mysql_query with a first parameter of $db. I edited my answer to provide more detail at the end. HTH!

Comment: $db is defined, I just chose not to include that part of the code.

Comment: @lunatiC well you've got the parameters in the wrong order it looks like.

Comment: The parameter problem is fixed, only got the problem that it is an invalid query.